# Paperclip v2.3.8 Not processing styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0.5 and Paperclip 2.3.8

when I define styles like

`has_attached_file :logo, :styles => {:std => "942x103>"}`

the "std" styled images are getting creating in my local machine. But when it runs in production machine, I just have `original` directory and not `std` directory in the images directory. what should have gone wrong.. how come it generates styled images in one environment and not doing the same in the other... please help

Comment: Is paperclip logging any errors related to not finding the imagemagick install?  It won't 500 in production when it can't use imagemagick but it should whine about it in the logs.

Comment: you should specify your production OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't got [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed on your production server.

You should install it and configure it for paperclip.

Good luck!